# How to get selection in a mailItem Body using outlook addin 2007 and VSTO c#

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, outlook-addin

I would like to highlight some text within the body of an e-mail and then click on something (toolbar button, etc)

```
Outlook.Application myApplication = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
              Outlook.Explorer myActiveExplorer = (Outlook.Explorer)myApplication.ActiveExplorer();

              Outlook.Selection selection = myActiveExplorer.Selection;

              if (selection.Count == 1 && selection[1] is Outlook.MailItem)
              {
                    Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)selection[1];

                    mail.Copy(); // currently opened mail

                    Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)
                 myApplication.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

                    mailItem.Subject = mail.Subject;
                    mailItem.To = mail.To;

                    mailItem.Body = ?????         // copy only selected text/images of user 

                    mailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceLow;
                    mailItem.Display(true);
              }
```

On the mailITem.Body, I just want to paste the selected text/images of the user from the selected mail (// currently opened mail).
How can I implement it, I cant  find the paste method. 
Whats the selected item And it stores to sql server database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

outlook cannot get the selected text in the mail body,so convert the outlook to word editor, so you can follow the 3 steps

```
1. get the mail total body
2. use the word editor based on the **microsoft.office.Interop.word** dll
3.select the text and to store the any string
```

the code is first add the dll reference

```
object oItem;
Outlook.Application oApp=new Outlook.Application();
 Outlook.Explorer oExp=oApp.ActiveExplorer();
 Outlook.Selection oSel= oExp.Selection;
 for (i = 1; i <= oSel.Count; i++)
                {
                    oItem = oSel[i];
        Outlook.MailItem oMail = (Outlook.MailItem)oItem;
Outlook.Inspector inspector = oMail.GetInspector;

            // Obtain the Word.Document object from the Inspector object
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document)inspector.WordEditor;
mailItem.Body = document.Application.Selection.Text;
}
```

i think it is help full